# text delimiter shifting values in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe like the data_df example below, that I create by reading in data from a csv with the code below.  the problem I’m running in to is that some of the values in some of the columns are getting shifted to the right.  For example the second record values are shifted one column to the right starting with the name column.  I think maybe there’s a “\” in the name for that record that’s causing the shift.  Does anyone know how to fix this, is there something I can do in read_csv that would address this?

Code:

```
data_df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(data_df[:5])
```

Output:

```
   Unnamed: 0  call_history_id                            calllog_id  \
0       16358       1210746736  ca58d850-6fe6-4673-a049-ea4a2d8d7ecf   
1       16361       1210976828  c005329b-955d-4d88-98a5-1c47e6a1cb80   
2       16402       1217791595  050e9b83-54c2-4c87-abdd-32225c0d3189   
3       16471       1228495414  45705ed1-a8e2-4a15-8941-5b0a40b7d409   
4       27906       1245173592  04e56818-04a0-4704-ac86-31c31dac2370   

        call_id  connection_id  pbx_name    pbx_id  extension_number  \
0  1.509170e+12   1.509170e+12  sales8x8  sales8x8               595   
1  1.509170e+12   1.509170e+12  sales8x8  sales8x8               595   
2  1.509170e+12   1.509170e+12  sales8x8  sales8x8               595   
3  1.509170e+12   1.509170e+12  sales8x8  sales8x8               595   
4  1.509170e+12   1.509170e+12  sales8x8  sales8x8               595   

  extension_id   customer_id      address                 name  \
0          595  2.525100e+29  14086694428           Sun Basket   
1          595  2.525100e+29  13214371589               PEREZ\   
2          595  2.525100e+29  14088566290          14088566290   
3          595  2.525100e+29   8059316676              Dialing   
4          595  2.525100e+29  12028071151  Implementation Team   

  start_timestamp     direction call_internal call_missed duration  \
0    1/8/18 19:49             I             0           0     4414   
1           BRYAN  1/8/18 20:09             I           0        0   
2    1/9/18 20:31             I             0           0    14766   
3   1/11/18 17:16             I             0           0     1686   
4   1/15/18 22:55             I             0           0     3491   

  device_model   group_call group_name group_number           device_id  \
0  mediaserver            0         \N           \N  MasterSlaveService   
1         8300  mediaserver          0           \N                  \N   
2  mediaserver            0         \N           \N  MasterSlaveService   
3  mediaserver            0         \N           \N  MasterSlaveService   
4  mediaserver            0         \N           \N  MasterSlaveService   

  history_event_state   created_time   updated_time    group_type  
0                   A   1/8/18 19:49   1/8/18 19:49            \N  
1  MasterSlaveService              A   1/8/18 20:09  1/8/18 20:09  
2                   A   1/9/18 20:31   1/9/18 20:31            \N  
3                   A  1/11/18 17:16  1/11/18 17:16            \N  
4                   A  1/15/18 22:55  1/15/18 22:55            \N
```

Comment: The delimiter of your file is `','` yet some of your fields use this special character. That name is almost certainly written as `'PEREZ, BRYAN'`, which wont parse properly. If you have control over the file, you should choose a different delimiter.

Comment: @ALollz Thank you for getting back to me so quickly the value looks like ",PEREZ\,BRYAN," is there a handy way to deal with the "\," when reading the data in with read_csv?  Or do I need to find/replace them all before reading them in?

Comment: @ALollz Thanks your previous comment that just disappeared worked nicely "sep=r'(?<!\\),'"

Comment: I think my suggestion wasn't nearly as correct as dmitriys solution. That will solve a lot of the issues at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` is an escape character. Since I take it the values in your file are not enclosed in quotes, the `\` is placed before the comma so that you treat `PEREZ, BRYAN` as one value.

Try passing `\\` to the `escapechar` option of `pd.read_csv` and this should take care of it, e.g. `pd.read_csv(filename, escapechar="\\")`.